# Embed MingW prompt window into ConEmu

Tags: windows, terminal, mingw, conemu

I failed to embed MingW window into ConEmu. I basically copy-pasted the Git Bash command for ConEmu `Settings > Starup > Tasks`:

```
set "PATH=%ConEmuDir%\..\msys64\usr\bin;%PATH%" & %ConEmuDir%\..\msys64\mingw64.exe --no-cd --command=/usr/bin/bash.exe -l -i -new_console:p
```

msys64 is installed under the same parent folder as ConEmu. But What I see after trying to open this new tab is that the MingW window quickly showed itself and then closed.

Please help.

Comment: Why don't you use default task created for you by ConEmu?

Comment: @Maximus The default task wasn't created when I installed the latest MingW long after I installed ConEmu.... Should I reinstall ConEmu?

Comment: Generally you should use [cygwin/msys connector](https://conemu.github.io/en/CygwinMsysConnector.html) to get msys shells work properly. Please don't use mingw.exe

Answer (score 1):

This is a task line for a Mingw64 ZSH shell (wrapped for better reading):

```
set CHERE_INVOKING=1 &
set "PATH=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;%PATH%" &
set MSYS2_PATH_TYPE=inherit &
set MSYSTEM=mingw64 &
set MSYSCON=conemu64.exe &
"C:\msys64\usr\bin\zsh.exe" --login -i -new_console:C:"C:\msys64\mingw64.exe"
```

[reference](https://www.programmersought.com/article/8984539350/)

Comment: I still can't `makepkg` a mingw package with a console such as this one.

Comment: It is not working for some reason.

This bash started by your receipt: 
# echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:/mingw64/bin:/c/Program Files/ConEmu/ConEmu/Scripts:/c/Program Files/ConEmu:/c/Program Files/ConEmu/ConEmu:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/........

and this started by standard C:\msys64\mingw64.exe:
# echo $PATH
/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/usr/share/java/gradle/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl

Comment: Update to the previous coment. This recipe is a bit wrong.  MSYSTEM=MINGW64 should be written CAPITALIZED, it's important. Also, you can skip set PATH=... it will be overriden internally. Now it working as expected.